# How to fix a function that is supposed to count the number of Heads over 100 trials?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that simply simulates a classic coin flipping situation where the probability of obtaining heads is equal to obtaining of tails and counts the observed Heads over 100 trials.

The code that I have tried to write, on the other hand, does not do it but returns either 0 or 1:

```
myCoinFlips <- function(prob = 0.5)
{
nFlips <- 100
   for(i in 1:length(nFlips)) {
count <- 0
result <- sample(c("Heads", "Tails"), 1, replace= TRUE, prob = 
c(prob, 1-prob))

   if (result[i] == "Heads") {
   count <- count + 1
   }
   }
 return(count)  
}
```

How can I fix this code so that it displays the number of Heads out of 100 trials?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems that are hidden by your bad indentation.

1. `count <- 0` should be outside of your loop.
2. You are using `result` as both a scalar and a vector. 
   Change `result[i]` to `result`
3. `nFlips` is a scalar, so `length(nFlips)` is 1. You need `for(i in 1:nFlips)`

Please indent your code properly and it will help you.

Comment: Sorry for indentation, I am also aware that I did an awkward indentation but I am pretty new with both R and Stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: I am happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

@G5W has already shown where the main *code syntax* issues are; to expand from that, you should consider improving the algorithm itself.

1. For example, simulating a single coin flip 100 times (`sample(c("Heads", "Tails"), 1)`) is the same (but a lot slower) as simulating 100 coin flips once (`sample(c("Heads", "Tails", 100, replace = T)`).
2. If you do sample once from `c("Heads", "Tails")` you don't need `replace = T`, because you only draw one from a total of two elements.
3. I recommend making `nFlips` a function argument to easily allow changing that parameter.

So an improved function `myCoinFlips2` could look like this

```
myCoinFlips2 <- function(prob = 0.5, nFlips = 100) {
    return(sum(sample(
        c("Heads", "Tails"), nFlips, replace = T, prob = c(prob, 1 - prob)) == "Heads"))
}
```

or since you're not storing the series of `"Heads"` and `"Tails"` just sum `TRUE` and `FALSE`

```
myCoinFlips3 <- function(prob = 0.5, nFlips = 100) {
    return(sum(sample(
        c(TRUE, FALSE), nFlips, replace = T, prob = c(prob, 1 - prob))))
}
```

---

To demonstrate how significant the performance increase can be when sampling `nFlips` coin flips once as opposed to sampling a single coin flip `nFlips` times we can run a `microbenchmark` for `nFlips = 10^6` coin flips

```
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    myCoinFlips = myCoinFlips(nFlips = 10^6),
    myCoinFlips2 = myCoinFlips2(nFlips = 10^6),
    myCoinFlips3 = myCoinFlips3(nFlips = 10^6),
    times = 10
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#         expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max
#  myCoinFlips 7118.30839 7379.53689 7646.05646 7722.00763 7840.07345 8235.95764
# myCoinFlips2   40.00080   41.51453   48.08246   47.16093   50.62694   65.41062
# myCoinFlips3   23.47758   25.20427   27.55469   26.36489   30.88384   32.17406

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Notice how `myCoinFlips` is 2 orders of magnitude slower than the other two methods.

Comment: This is very insightful for me! Will definitely keep in mind. But how about if I wanted to save the series of Heads and Tails? To complicate things a little bit, what should I do if I want my function to take in a vector of input for the prob or nFlips argument and store the result?

Comment: @e.erhan To return the vector of `"Heads"` and `"Tails"` you'd just need to have your function return the output of `sample(c("Heads", "Tails"), nFlips, ...)` (instead of summing those that are equal to `"Heads"`).